# Debugging VS2008 C++ project on non-dev machine

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2008

I am experienced in debugging C++ in Visual Studio on the development machine, running a debug session and then breaking into the code when an Assert or Exception is encountered.

But now I want this same facility when I am testing the project on another machine, specifically to see the break location, call stack, variable values, etc.

What are the best ways to achieve this?  Obviously a Debug build is required, what else must be transferred to the test machine?

Is it only the PDB and ILK files generated during the build, or all the source code files as well?

In which case, how is VS on the test machine supposed to recognise the source files and associate them with the deployed test binaries?

And then they would need to be recopied across for every single rebuild?

Comment: `Obviously a Debug build is required, what else must be transferred to the test machine? `  No.  You can't redistribute debug builds that are reliant on the debug VS runtime libraries to machines that do not have VS installed.  Investigate "Remote Debugging": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx

Comment: Thanks Paul, both machines have VS2008 installed. I'm just trying to give the test machine access to the source of the project so I can properly examine the context of any crashes.  Sounds like Remote Debugging is about running the executable on the test machine while operating from the dev machine?  But I want to be sitting at the test machine when debugging.

Comment: You do not have to be at the test machine when you do remote debugging.  You *are* running the program on the test machine when doing remote debugging, but you are actually sitting at your development machine setting breakpoints, watching variables, etc.   You're communicating with the test machine using TCP/IP and have a remote machine running the debug monitor app (MSVSMON.EXE I believe).  So there is no need at all to be sitting at the test machine -- that is what remote debugging is all about.

Comment: In addition, all you need on the test machine is the same build of your app running as your development machine and that you can connect to the machine (again through an IP address).  You don't need source code or any other files on the test machine.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I did get remote debugger working.  Not exactly what I was looking for, but much better than what I had, and together with a TeamViewer session, gets me moving forward again.  Sorry I couldn't mark your comments as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a source server, then the only thing you need will be copying the pdbs over, and configure the Visual Studio to use source server (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242029(v=vs.90).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx)

This article (http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know) has some great information of source server and PDBs.

Comment: Thanks Peon, these are good references, but Source Server looks tricky to set up, and depends on Perl (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680641(v=vs.85).aspx).  I'm wondering if I should be thinking about setting up a source control system like VisualSVN?